# entity framework distinct by field

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

i have table kopija that goes like this:
idKopija | idFilm | nije_tu 
   1     |     1 |       0 
   2      |    1 |      0 
   3       |   1  |     1
   4        |  2   |    1 and etc.

And i have query that goes like this:

```
var upit = from f in baza.films
join z in baza.zanrs on f.idZanr equals z.idZanr
join k in baza.kopijas on f.idFilm equals k.idFilm
select new
{
                           idFilm = f.idFilm,
                           nazivFilm = f.naziv,
                           nazivZanr = z.naziv,
                           idZanr = f.idZanr,
                           godina = f.godina,
                           slika = f.slika,
                           klip = f.klip,
                           nijeTu = k.nije_tu
                       };
if (checkBox1.Checked)
                upit = upit.Where(k => k.nijeTu == 0).Distinct();
            else
            {
                upit = upit.Where(k => k.nijeTu == 0 || k.nijeTu == 1).Distinct();
            }
```

Now i want to make a distinct list of "idFilm". But prolem is that I get idFilm on two places because one of them has nije_tu=0 and other one has nije_tu=1.
Please someone help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
upit.Where(k => k.nijeTu == 0 || k.nijeTu == 1).Select(x => x.idFilm).Distinct();
```

?

Comment: I need all of those columns I selected in first query not just idFilm. I want query to show me idFilm distinct, but also give me all those I selected. I continue adding .Where clause to query after this line.

Comment: Okay, then you could do something like: `upit.Where(k => k.nijeTu == 0 || k.nijeTu == 1).GroupBy(x => x.idFilm).Select(y => y.First());`

Comment: I was excited when I saw GroupBy, I forgot about that... But when I use it I get error `Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,AnonymousType#1>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' D:\dev\c#\VideoKlub\VideoKlub\FormFilmovi.cs 245 28 VideoKlub
`